# Magento 2 run model before Payment Method

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I have a problem that I can't solve, I need to stop the execution of the payment process, if my model returns false

i have:

app\code\vendor\Sales\etc\webapi_rest\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
       <observer name="order_place_before" instance="vendor\Sales\Model\Before" />
    </event>  
</config>
```

if I use a checkmo payment method (magento standard) the verification that I do in the model works, but if I use the ADYEN payment method, it stays on the payment page, but it does not return an error, I wanted my MODEL to run before the Adyen module

how do i make my MODEL run first, and if it returns false, don't process payment with Adyen

my Model:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        
        try{

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->save();
    
            $orderId = $order->getId();

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            //get token
            $token = $this->getToken();  
            $certificateID = $this->createCertificateId($token, $orderId);
           
            $order->setData("increment_id",$certificateID)->save();
          
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            $this->_messageManager->addError('error');
            exit;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have not shared your model so i am hoping you are expecting something close to this, if you will share your then may be i can assist you better, but for now you can try this sample code

```
public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, $result)
{
    $postcode = $this->cartModel->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $country = $this->cartModel->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
    $province = $this->cartModel->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
    $paymentMethodCode = $subject->getCode();

    if ($paymentMethodCode == 'method-code') {
        return $result; //Return result for true scenario. return true wont work
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edit and show my Model